# Quotient respect to an equivalence relation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

I have the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, in ZF.

I want to construct the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ taking the quotient respect to usual the equivalence relation $R$ on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ that is $(a,b)R(c,d) \iff a+d=b+c$.

I have to construct a set $X=\mathbb{Z}$ that contains the equivalence classes.

What is the correct ZF formulation for this set?

I think it's something like $X:=\{a \ | (\ b\in a, c\in a)  \Rightarrow (b,c)\in R \}$

The problem is: if $a$ are the particular equivalence classes, from what set should I take them (for let $X$ be a ZF set)?

Comment: An equivalence class is a subset of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$, so they live in $\mathcal P(\mathbb N\times\mathbb N)$. Another option is to consider the quotient $(\mathbb N\times\mathbb N)/R$ as the image of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ under a function f that preserves $R$: if $xRy$ then $f(x)=f(y)$. This function can, for example, send a class to one representative of the class.

Comment: Note that as stated, the elements of your set X may only be subsets of equivalence classes. You need a little more to get them to be maximal.

Comment: @fpe: The relation itself is a subset of N x N. The equivalence classes are just subsets of N. And the quotient construction you propose would require the axiom of choice, whereas here we are working in ZF.

Comment: @NateEldredge: sorry for the typo about equivalence classes, unfortunately I can't edit my comment anymore. As for your remark, here we could choose a representative without requiring AC (taking the pair that is minimal for the lexicographic order or whatnot). But cheers for correcting me!